# why am i getting this linker error while creating archive of my project in xcode 7.2.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to create archive of my project and everytime i am getting this error:

```
ld: can't open output file for writing:    /Users/ranbeerhora/Documents/KicksendRepo/KickSend/trunk/KicksendiOSSwift /Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/KickSend/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/KickSend.build/Release-iphoneos/KickSend.build/Objects-normal/arm64/KickSend, errno=21 for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

i have tried different things but none of the solution works.

Comment: Have you tried to Clean (⇧⌘K) and rebuild the project?

Comment: yes i have done that too.Its still giving me that error.I accessed the directory given in the error and there were two folders arm64 and armv7 inside objects-normal folder but the 'Kicksend' directory is created in only armv7 not in arm64 after building the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.I was not giving path of the objective-c bridging header file in the build setting, when i gave the file path it worked.

## **Explanation:**

xcode was not able to open output file for writing because it was not able to access that file since the path was not given when i gave the path xcode found the file and i was able to create the archive.

Comment: what setting in Build Settings?

Comment: search **objective-c bridging** in build settings